# Autorun Tomcat in Linux Mandriva - java.io.IOException: invalid argument

Tags: boot, startup, tomcat

Here's the autorun script, which i use -

```
#!/bin/sh

    # description: Tomcat start/stop script
    # chkconfig:

    TOMCAT_PATH=/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/bin
    TOMCAT_START=$TOMCAT_PATH/startup.sh
    TOMCAT_STOP=$TOMCAT_PATH/shutdown.sh

    start()
    {
    if [ -x ${TOMCAT_START} ]; then
    echo "Starting tomcat server..."
    ${TOMCAT_START} &
    else
    echo "Cannot start tomcat server"
    fi
    }

    stop()
    {
    if [ -x ${TOMCAT_STOP} ]; then
    echo "Stopping tomcat server"
    ${TOMCAT_STOP} &
    else
    echo "Cannot stop tomcat server..."
    fi
    }

    restart()
    {
    stop
    sleep 10
    start
    }

    case "$1" in
    'start')
    start
    ;;
    'stop')
    stop
    ;;
    'restart')
    restart
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Please supply an argument [start|stop|restart]"
    esac
```

I put it in -

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/
```

I added it to the startup:

```
/sbin/chkconfig --add --level 345 tomcat
```

But when i reboot the system, watch the logs and see -

**catalina.out**:

```
...
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
jan 03, 2013 6:09:04 PM hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter destroy
INFO: CharacterEncodingFilter destroyed.
jan 03, 2013 6:09:04 PM javax.jmdns.impl.tasks.state.DNSStateTask run
WARNING: Canceler(www-...-ru.local.).run() exception 
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:676)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.send(JmDNSImpl.java:1537)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.tasks.state.DNSStateTask.run(DNSStateTask.java:131)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

The process does not start.

But if i execute the command -

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat start
```

The process starts well.

Why does it not start automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: don't you need to add some kind of pre-requisit?
It's failing on java.net most likely it's trying to start when your network services are not up yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alexandre Alves!
Yes, i thought about it. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: add a symlink in /etc/rc[3-5].d/S90tomcat pointing to your start script and try again.
I'm assuming that Mandriva still uses the start scripts as Redhat and not the new ones.
I choose a S90 to "ensure" that network will be up when it is called.

Comment: @ivanov-void Do you have network up and running when Tomcat starts up?

Comment: @ivanov-void Can you post output of `who -r` and `ls /etc/rc.d/rc<rl>.d/` for the appropriate runlevel after the machine starts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support,  Karlson! Sorry that did not notice, was busy with the problem. Now everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a little shell-script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Startup script for Tomcat
#

JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09" ;
JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre;
CATALINA_HOME=/java/tomcat-7.0.27;
export JAVA_HOME && export JRE_HOME &&$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh &&$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh

case "$1" in
start)
echo -n "Starting Tomcat"
su - tomcat -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping Tomcat"
su - tomcat -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
;;
restart)
$0 stop
$0 start
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Then put it in

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d
```

Added the rights to run:

```
# chmod +x /etc/init.d/ tomcat
```

Added symbolic links:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc0.d/K91tomcat
ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc1.d/K91tomcat
ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc2.d/S91tomcat
ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc3.d/S91tomcat
ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc4.d/S91tomcat
ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc5.d/S91tomcat
ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc6.d/K91tomcat
```

Now all is well.

```
reboot;
```

**catalina.out**:

```
...
INFO: Server startup in 113947 ms
```

Thanks a lot!